# My file keeps on being closed after .write()

Tags: python

Here is this block of code I'm trying to finish:

```
elif parameter == 'statistics':
    outfile.write(stats(infile))
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
```

So essentially, I am trying to write the statistics of the file into the new file that is being copied. The statistics works and everything as when I open the file, the statistics are written in. However, I noticed because of the two outfile.write it seems to close after the first one, so only the statistics go in and not the rest of the content in the original file.

The error that I am getting is this:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I am unsure why the file is closing.

**EDIT: Here is the whole code, as requested**

```
def copy_file():
    infile_name = input("Please enter the name of the file to copy: ")
    infile = open(infile_name, 'r', encoding='utf8')
    parameter = input("Please enter a parameter(line numbers, Gutenberg trim, statistics, none): ")
    outfile_name = input("Please enter the name of the new copy:  ")
    outfile = open(outfile_name, 'w', encoding='utf8')
    counter = 1
    if parameter == 'line numbers':
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(f' {counter:6}: {line}')
            counter += 1
    elif parameter == 'Gutenberg trim':
        copyStart = False
        for line in infile:
            #print(line.strip())
            if '*** START' in line.strip():
                copyStart = True
                continue
            elif '*** END' in line.strip():
                copyStart = False
                break
            if copyStart == True:
                outfile.write(line)
    elif parameter == 'statistics':
        outfile.write(stats(infile))
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
    else:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
copy_file()
```

**EDIT2: So sorry for not including it. Here is the stats function:**

```
def stats(text) -> str:
    with text as infile:
        totallines = 0
        emplines = 0
        characters = 0
        for line in infile:
            totallines += 1
            characters += len(line)
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                emplines += 1
        lines = totallines - emplines
        totalaveChars = characters/totallines
        nonempaveChars = characters/lines
        result = (f'{totallines:5} lines in list \n'
                  f'{emplines:5} empty lines in list \n'
                  f'{totalaveChars:5.1f} average characters per line \n'
                  f'{nonempaveChars:5.1f} average chars per non-empty line')
        return result
print(stats(open('ASH.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')))
```

Here is the result from stats:

```
13052 lines in list 
2666 empty lines in list 
44.6 average characters per line 
56.0 average chars per non-empty line
```

Comment: Can you add the whole code? From this fragment it seems that the file is not even opened at any time.

Comment: Can you show how you open the file?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I have edited it and added the whole function
EDIT: though I guess I didn't have to include the other parts...

Comment: `outfile.write(stats(infile))`

What does the method  stats do? 

Because from what I see, you might be not returning anything or closes the file.

Comment: Maybe it's talking about `infile` and not `outfile`?

Comment: Could you give us what the `stats` function does?

Comment: What does `stats` do? Maybe it closes the file?

Comment: I have edited in the stats function. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Well you got it ! `stats` close the file. So ater you call it, you got a close file error. It's the `wtih` statement that close the file, you do not actually need it.

Comment: Ooooh. I see that I have not completely comprehend what with does. This makes total sense. I will rid of the with statement and see that it should work. Thank you!

Comment: I just rid the with statement and the error went away. Although, the for loop does not seem to have ran and the file still has only the statistics of the file in it and have not actually copied the original file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the `stats` function. The with statement will close the file with the local name text, which is infile in your case!

```
def stats(text) -> str:
    totallines = 0
    emplines = 0
    characters = 0
    for line in text:
        totallines += 1
        characters += len(line)
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:
            emplines += 1
    lines = totallines - emplines
    totalaveChars = characters/totallines
    nonempaveChars = characters/lines
    result = (f'{totallines:5} lines in list \n'
              f'{emplines:5} empty lines in list \n'
              f'{totalaveChars:5.1f} average characters per line \n'
              f'{nonempaveChars:5.1f} average chars per non-empty line')
    return result
```

In your main program, you passed to the function `stats` the variable `infile`, which is a file. You do not need to reopen it with `with` inside the stats functions. Moreover, `with` will ensure the closing at the end. Thus in your main loop, the `infile` is closed after the call on `stats`.

Comment: Also, if this is a public API, this function should not be public because it's an internal function. So maybe rename it to `_stats`.

Comment: Seeing as he doesn't really get yet how `with` works, let's keep it simple ^^

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you for explaining it. Upon removing the with statement, the error went away. Although, I have hit an unusual issue where only the statistics of the file is going into the new file. The original file is not being copied into the file. It's almost as if the for loop was completely ignored for some reason

Comment: @Mathieu Sure, but I only suggested to change the name of the function.

Comment: @GhostArk `seek(0)` after `stats` to get back to the beginning of the file.

Comment: @FurkanKambay Yes, but the explanation of the why do so might be a bit harsh ^^

Comment: @GhostArk The reason the for loop is ignore is that in stats, the for loop on the lines brings you to the end of the file (`for line in text`). You can see this behavior as having in the file object a pointer which points to the current line. If you don't tell him to get back to the beginning, it won't.

Comment: I see. And I would be able to achieve telling it to go back to the beginning by using outfile.seek(0) as @FurkanKambay had said?

Comment: @GhostArk Not outfile, but infile. But yes.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I will study up on seek as well. Again, much appreciated for your time and help. @everyone else here too

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
def copy_file():
    infile_name = input("Please enter the name of the file to copy: ")
    parameter = input("Please enter a parameter(line numbers, Gutenberg trim, statistics, none): ")
    outfile_name = input("Please enter the name of the new copy:  ")
    counter = 1
    with open(infile_name, 'r', encoding='utf8') as infile:
      with open(outfile_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
          if parameter == 'line numbers':
              for line in infile:
                  outfile.write(f' {counter:6}: {line}')
                  counter += 1
          elif parameter == 'Gutenberg trim':
              copyStart = False
              for line in infile:
                  #print(line.strip())
                  if '*** START' in line.strip():
                      copyStart = True
                      continue
                  elif '*** END' in line.strip():
                      copyStart = False
                      break
                  if copyStart == True:
                      outfile.write(line)
          elif parameter == 'statistics':
              outfile.write(stats(infile))
              for line in infile:
                  outfile.write(line)
          else:
              for line in infile:
                  outfile.write(line)
    copy_file()
```

Using `with open(filename, 'r') as file:` it will automatically close the file once the operation has finished, and not before.

Comment: While this is an improvement, I don't believe it's the answer to this specific problem.

Comment: I doubt it solves the problem. What he wrote is correct in term of opening / closing. And the 2 with statements can be combined in 1.

Comment: @FurkanKambay hmm yes you're correct. Looking back over I cannot explicitly see why it's closing. I guess then it's an issue elsewhere in the code that hasn't been uploaded.

Comment: Ah, sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>      elif parameter == 'statistics':
>          outfile.write(stats(infile))
>          for line in infile:
>              outfile.write(line)
> ```
>
> ... only the statistics go in and not the rest of the content in the
>   original file ...

My educated guess is that the `stats` function *consumes* and possibly
closes the input stream (IS).

If `stats` is somehow well behaved and limits itself to consuming the
IS, one can *rewind* it

```
           ...
           infile.seek(0) # rewind the input stream
           for line in infile:
               outfile.write(line)
```

If, on the other hand, `stats` is a bit disruptive and closes
altogether the IS one can use the `.name` attribute of the file object
to reopen it, like this

```
           ...
           for line in open(infile.name):
               outfile.write(line)
```

This second solution works even in the first, milder hypotesis and
works even if the code was passed the `infile` file object from a
outer call.

Another possibility, if you can access and modify the `stats` source
code, is to *undo* the reading performed by the function, memorizing
the current position in the input stream before any `read` operation
and later rewind the IS to that position

```
def stats(infile):
    ...
    current_pos = infile.tell()
    # do your stuff
    ...
    infile.seek(current_pos)
    return workload
```

For this to work, of course, the file object has not to be closed
before the `.seek()`, either explicitly (by a `.close()`) or
implicitly (by falling outside the scope of a `with` block).
If this is your situation (closed file), please remove either the
explicit `infile.close()` or the (unnecessary) `with` statement and
the rewind will be correct.